# How to correctly redirect all http requests to https

Tags: .htaccess, https, yourls

I have a functional URL shortening site. Recently I added SSL to the website and configured the `.htaccess` for proper redirecting.  The issue is that all of the `http://` requests, redirect back to the homepage `https://websi.te`

Currently, I've tried setting up redirecting as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

An example of what's going wrong:

User types `http://websi.te/keyword` or `websi.te/keyword` and they are redirected to `https://websi.te` instead of `https://websi.te/keyword`

Answer (score 0):

Change your rewrite to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

$1 is first group match ^(.*)$, it's your request.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still facing the same issue even with this rewrite rule.